# Starting AlarmManager in Android (C#)

Tags: android, xamarin, alarmmanager

I saw and used this link: [Creating And Scheduling Alarms Using AlarmManager In Android](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-and-scheduling-alarms-in-android/)

Now I have this code:

```
namespace AlarmManage
{
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Time Up... Now Vibrating !!!",
                    ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context
                    .GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
            vibrator.Vibrate(2000);
        }  
    }
}

public void startAlertAtParticularTime()
{
    // alarm first vibrate at 14 hrs and 40 min and repeat itself at ONE_HOUR interval  
    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyBroadcastReceiver));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(
            this, 280192, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
    calendar.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
    calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 14);
    calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, 49);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
    alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.IntervalHour, pendingIntent);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Alarm will vibrate at time specified", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

I also set "SET-ALARM" and "VIBRATE" in Manifest.

My problem: I do not see the output "Time Up... Now Vibrating !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't successfully declare your `MyBroadcastReceiver`, in xamarin, we can use:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
```

to declare this broadcast. It's like declare it in traditional android manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

So, `MyBroadcastReceiver` should be like this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Time Up... Now Vibrating !!!",
                ToastLength.Long).Show();
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context
                .GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
        vibrator.Vibrate(2000);
    }
}
```

Now you can get the toast: "Time Up... Now Vibrating !!!"